# JNDI Two SSL For weblogic uisng thint3client

Tags: weblogic, jndi

I am looking for an example or reference code on how to achieve the two-way SSL authentication with JNDI in Weblogic using wlthint3client.jar as the dependency.

Below is the sample code snippet which works with the wlfullclient.jar in the classpath.

```
    //Initialize the Environment with necessary details...
    Environment env = new weblogic.jndi.Environment();
    env.setInitialContextFactory(factory);
    env.setProviderUrl(providerUrl);
    
    //Configure the trust manager with trusted certificates
//I am getting the exception mentioned in Error Snippet 1
    TrustManager tm = new weblogic.security.SSL.WLSTrustManager(sslRootCACerts);
    env.setSSLClientTrustManager(tm);
    

    //Load the client identity 
    Certificate[] sslClientCerts = .....; // Get the Client Trust Certificates
    PrivateKey clientKey = .......; ////Get the Client Key Certificate
    env.loadLocalIdentity(sslClientCerts, clientKey); //Load the user identity //Here, I am getting the exception mentioned in Error Snippet 2
    
    //Customize the SSL protocol
    SSLClientInfo sslClientInfo = (SSLClientInfo)Security.getThreadSSLClientInfo();
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslClientInfo.getSSLSocketFactory();
    
    //Create the context with above information.
    env.getInitialContext();
```

However, above code doesn't work when I replace the wlfullclient.jar with the wlthint3client.jar. Below is the exception I am getting.

Error Snippet 1

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This method is not supported on the standalone WebLogic client
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.SSL.ClientSSLProxyImpl.setTrustManager(ClientSSLProxyImpl.java:89)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.setSSLClientTrustManager(Environment.java:1163)
    at com.sample.WebLogicInitialContextFactoryThinClient.getInitialContext(WebLogicInitialContextFactoryThinClient.java:109)
```

Error Snippet 2

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This method is not supported on the standalone WebLogic client
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.SSL.ClientSSLProxyImpl.loadLocalIdentity(ClientSSLProxyImpl.java:101)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.loadLocalIdentity(Environment.java:1429)
```

Thanks
Param

Comment: What is the error code/message ?

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin, Updated with the exception which I am getting. Sorry, I missed to include the error snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use weblogic.jar instead of wlthint3client.jar in your classpath.